# Unable to deploy django to python 3.8/Linux 2 on Elastic Beanstalk due to "postgresql95-devel is not available to be installed"

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, psycopg2

This is my requirements.txt:

```
asgiref==3.3.1
boto3==1.17.23
botocore==1.20.23
certifi==2020.12.5
cffi==1.14.5
chardet==4.0.0
cryptography==3.4.6
defusedxml==0.7.1
Django==3.1.7
django-allauth==0.44.0
django-cors-headers==3.7.0
django-rest-auth==0.9.5
djangorestframework==3.12.2
idna==2.10
jmespath==0.10.0
oauthlib==3.1.0
psycopg2==2.8.6
pycparser==2.20
PyJWT==2.0.1
python-dateutil==2.8.1
python3-openid==3.2.0
pytz==2021.1
requests==2.25.1
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
s3transfer==0.3.4
six==1.15.0
sqlparse==0.4.1
urllib3==1.26.3
```

The main error message I see in my logs is:
postgresql95-devel is not available to be installed. I am able to deploy a similar requirements.txt in an older environment (python 3.6) but for some reason this fails when on python 3.8. I even used the same deployment.zip that succeeded in 3.6 but this suddenly fails in 3.8. Is this a configuration error or a versioning error? Not sure how to debug this.

Comment: Use `psycopg2-binary` instead of `psycopg2` to get rid of the PostgreSQL dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

That means [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) not installed. Try to install it and try again.